# Gruping Grid GXT 2

Tags: gxt

How can I put the total values of a group of the grid in the same line with the type of the group?

Like:
[-] Fruits                     $4.00

Banana                         $2.00

Apple                          $2.00

So when I have the group collapsed, I have this

[+] Fruits  $4.00

Answer (score 0):

Use `Live Group Summary`. Link: [Sencha GXT 2 LiveGroupSummary Example](http://www.sencha.com/examples-2/#livegroupsummary)

If you want to show the summary row at top, it will be a difficult task as there is no direct way of doing it.

You have  GXT classes `GroupingView` and `GroupViewSummary` which extends `GroupingView`. You can see in the `doRender` method of `GroupingView`, the header text is being generated. You will have to override the method by following the steps of `renderSummary` method of `GroupSummaryView`. The header and summary, both are created in different classes, so it will be  a difficult task. Just follow the implementation of `GroupViewSummary` which extends `GroupingView` and change the `renderSummary` and `doRender` method according to your need.

I will not suggest doing so, because it might break the functionality.

Comment: Actually, I'm using it. I just want to put the total itens in the top of the grouping.

Comment: @danypr23 Edited my answer, its not exactly answering the question, but it provides what can be done